# Default derivation paths

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

I'd like to know all of the default derivation paths used by both software and hardware wallets for bitcoin.  According to https://iancoleman.io/bip39/?#english, the following are defaults:

- m/0'/0' (bitcoin core)
- m/0'/0 (Multibit)
- m/44'/0'/0' (blockchain.info)
- m/44'/0'/0'/0 (Electrum, Mycelium)
- m/49'/0'/0'/0 (p2wpkh-in-p2sh)
- m/84'/0'/0'/0 (p2wpkh bech32)

Am I missing any?

Comment: The one for electrum is wrong. Electrum's legacy addresses use m/0/n (m/1/n for change) and for p2wpkh they use [bip84](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0084.mediawiki). Electrum lets you restore bip39 seeds and gives you the option to select from bip44/49 for those but it doesn't use those for it's native seeds.

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, an awesome resource is https://walletsrecovery.org/.

This is a project whose goal is exactly to list the derivation paths of current and past software and hardware wallets.

Answer (score 4):

I have not verified the validity of this, or if it's up to date, but there is a spreadsheet tracking this, which might be helpful, at https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=584F122BA17116EE!313&app=Excel.

Summary:

```
Wallet                            BIP-32?   HD path

Armory (wallet 1.0) No  -
Bitcoin Core (version 0.13+)      Yes       m/0'/0'/i'
Bitcoin Wallet                    Yes       BIP-32
Bither                            Yes       m/44'/0'/0'/c/i
breadwallet                       Yes       BIP-32
Coinomi                           Yes       m/44'/0'/0'/c/i
Electrum (1.x wallet)             No        -
Electrum (2.x standard wallet)    Yes       m/c/i
Electrum (2.6+ BIP-39 wallet)     Yes       BIP-44
Hive (mobile and web)             Yes       BIP-32
MultiBit HD (BIP-44 wallet)       Yes       m/44'/0'/0'/c/i
MultiBit HD (standard wallet)     Yes       BIP-32
Mycelium for Android              Yes       BIP-44
Mycelium for iOS                  Yes       BIP-44
myTREZOR                          Yes       BIP-44
Wallet32 for Android (0.1 wallet) Yes       m/a/c/i
Wallet32 for Android (0.2 wallet) Yes       m/a/c/i
Wallet32 for Android (0.3 wallet) Yes       m/a'/c/i
Wallet32 for Android (0.4 wallet) Yes       m/0/0'/a'/c/i
Wallet32 for Android (0.5 wallet) Yes       BIP-44
```

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience I can say that Bitcoin Wallet for Android may use the path `m/1'`

Comment: Is that account or address 1?

Comment: @VincentAlex account