# How to find/view derivation path in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have found many default derivation path online which is used in bitcoin core, but i still can't get the correct one so that i can import my bitcoin wallet to my electrum wallet (BIP 39 option) with 18 words seed which i had got from bitsblock.io while initial download. I wanted to know how can we exactly find the derivation path in Qt GUI, as i had found a command online `wallet.keystore.derivation` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please help as i don't have enough knowledge in coding

Comment: bitsblock.io is not Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 2):

> How to find/view derivation path in **Bitcoin Core**

See [Default derivation paths](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/78993/13866)

> so that i can import my bitcoin wallet to my electrum wallet

I've read this cannot be done in Electrum.

> 18 words seed which i had got from **bitsblock.io** while initial download.

That's not Bitcoin core!

The bitsblock.io website copied the visual style of Bitcoin.org -- which seems a bit suspicious?

It is a recently created domain

```
Domain Name: BITSBLOCK.IO
Creation Date: 2019-10-23T15:24:40Z
```

Comment: Looks like a scam.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can not, they are completely incompatible.

Bitcoin Core uses hardened derivation and Electrum does not.

Comment: but still if we need to know the path from Bitcoin Core then how can we?