# Why importing private key from one HD wallet to another doesn't restore the balance?

Tags: wallet, address, bip32-hd-wallets, public-key

I've seen similar questions here but didn't find an answer
I look for a private key in Exodus, for example, and import it to Jaxx and I don't see my balance correctly
So my questions is, do all HD wallets generate public keys from private in the same way?
Also, for example, there are wallets that do not allow to generate new public address, does it mean that wallet is bad?
And if public keys aren't generated in the same way then does it even make sense to keep you private key on paper wallet if you won't be able to get your funds then?

Answer (score 1):

> do all HD wallets generate public keys from private in the same way?

No, the "derivation path" is an important additional piece of information. You should be prompted for this when importing / sweeping a private-key

See [Default derivation paths](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/78993/13866)

Comment: Thanks.  
So, I understand, that the best practice is to avoid wallets which derivation path I don't know(if I want to be able to then restore funds sent to it's addresses)?  
I experimented with multiple wallets and made a conclusion that loosing your funds is pretty easy

Comment: @Vid, I expect the derivation path for any popular or well-known wallet should be findable online without too much trouble. I feel it is a good idea to practise restoring a wallet from backup, from private-key (etc) or from the seed-phrase/recovery-phrase.

Answer (score 0):

In Exodus every address have private key maybe you import address with zero balance. To import all you must do it through 12-word recovery phrase.

Comment: I saw balances and imported the one with nonzero