# Exporting seed phrase from BitPay to other Wallets

Tags: bitpay

I'm trying to understand how can I access wallet funds (that I created with BitPay and have seed and extended pk for) on other wallets (BTC core, trust, blockchain.com or exodus for example).
If I try to import just the direct seed into these apps, I get an empty wallet (if I import it in bitpay it shows that funds are there). I'm just trying to understand, what to do in case there is no more bitpay for example. I found a bitpay/copay recovery tool on GitHub, but don't seem to fully understand what it does. Can someone please explain why seeds from bitpay don't work on other apps, and if there is something to do about it.

Comment: or every wallet uses its own seed phrases ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems BitPay [uses BIP39 seed phrases](https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025484512-Missing-transactions-Why-is-my-transaction-unconfirmed-) so you should be able to restore that wallet using any other wallet software which uses BIP39 or which allows you to select BIP39 instead of a proprietary scheme (e.g. Electrum).

The other main factor is derivation paths. You'll need to choose a wallet that either uses the same derivation path or which allows you to specify the correct derivation path.

I believe the BitPay wallet may be derived from the Copay wallet. [One website](https://walletsrecovery.org/) gives the following information:

> - Single Signer:
>
>   - ≥ v1.2 m/44/0'/X' (X increments with each wallet addition)
> - Multisig:
>
>   - < v1.2 m/45'/2147483647/0/x m/45'/2147483647/1/y
>   - ≥ v1.2 m/44/0'/0'
>   - ≥ v1.5 m/48'/0'/0'/1' m/48'/0'/0'/2'

I don't know how accurate that is.

---

Useful references

- [Default derivation paths](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/78993/13866)
- [Wallets Recovery](https://walletsrecovery.org/)
- [BIP-44 - Multi-Account Hierarchy for Deterministic Wallets](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki)
- [I can't use BitPay anymore. How can I recover my funds from the BitPay wallet?](https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000244486-I-can-t-use-BitPay-anymore-How-can-I-recover-my-funds-from-the-BitPay-wallet-)

Comment: thanks you for your comment, will read up

Comment: Also the BIP39 passphrase needs to match, including a null one.